# Where can I find an image of the gut/anatomy of the mealworm?

Tags: entomology, dissection

Specifically, I'm a student working on an experiment involving the dissection of the mealworm *(Tenebrio molitor)* but for the life of me, I can't seem to find an image *anywhere* on the internet. Speaking to Carolina.com also got me no results. We're looking to dissect the mealworm and extract its gut/GI tract. However, at the moment it seems like we're going in blind. Is there anyone out there who can provide some insight?

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find which showed the inside of a mealworm not just the outside was this:

[image]

Taken from [here](https://www.pinterest.com/Ronbc/worms/). Hope this helps with your dissection.

Answer (score 0):

There is a paper called: biodegradation and Mineralization of Polystyrene by Plastic-Eating Mealworms: Part 2. Role of Gut Microorganisms. I. Here you can find a picture of the midgut lumen. [image]